# Batch file not accepting spaces in for /f

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This command does not work it wont accept spaces in the path name and I cant figure out how to fix it please help

```
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (E:\NON-school stuff\space space\a.txt) do echo %%x
```

I have tried everything please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one trick is to transform your filename into a short filename, so it may be accepted by any command without problems

```
for %%a in ("\some dir\some text.txt") do echo %%~sa
```

in your case

```
for %%a in ("E:\NON-school stuff\space space\a.txt") do for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (%%~sa) do echo %%x
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy fix.

```
set "sourceFile=E:\NON-school stuff\space space\a.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("%sourceFile%") do echo %%x
```

Anytime you have spaces in file paths you need to quote them and if you read the help for the FOR /F command you will see that the usebackq option allows you to use quotes when you have spaces in file names. If you don't use the usebackq option it treats the file name as a string.

Comment: I slightly modified this to avoid the horizontal scroll.  If it goes against your original intent please change it back, no hard feelings if you do.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate looks fine.